# Infomatica ISO-8601 date

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am using Informatica Powercenter and need to insert strings/dates similar to this one from a flat file to Oracle.

2013-07-23T13:55:33.0000000-04:00

In Oracle the solution is

```
to_timestamp_tz(‘2013-07-23T13:55:33.0000000-04:00’,’YYYY-MM-DD”T”HH24:MI:SS.FF7TZR’)
```

What is the best way to convert this string/date so that Informatica will interpret it correctly?  None of the Informatica expressions I see handle the "-4:00" correctly.

Comment: If you do not need the timezone information, you can use substr to remove the -04:00 part and convert the rest to date/time using TO_DATE function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done, what is you target table ,I know for teradata as below

create you column in you target table as  **TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE**
keep the value of data in a varchar column and connect it to the target column (mentioned above)
use TPT as you load and it will load the data.

If you are using oracle table find the equivalent.

Comment: **TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE** column datatype is also there in Oracle use above procedure and keep the normal load as TPT is not there.